# Neo4j Java Embedded Shortestpath

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using this custom expander for `Neo4j` embedded using the shortestpath algorithm. However the shortestpath algorithm doesn't allow me to look up the last relationship in the path it's constructed because they haven't implemented it. I get an unsupported exception.

I just need to check the property of the last relationship to keep expanding. Is there a way to do this?

```
public class CustomExpander implements PathExpander {

        private Integer conditionFromTime;
        private Integer conditionToTime;
        private Integer conditionDayInd;
        private Node startNode; 
        private Node endNode;

        public CustomExpander( Integer fromTime, Integer toTime, Integer dayInd, Node startNode ) {
            this.conditionFromTime = fromTime;
            this.conditionToTime = toTime;
            this.conditionDayInd = dayInd;
            this.startNode = startNode;
            this.endNode = endNode;
        }
        public CustomExpander( Integer fromTime, Integer toTime, Integer dayInd, Node startNode,Node endNode ) {
            this.conditionFromTime = fromTime;
            this.conditionToTime = toTime;
            this.conditionDayInd = dayInd;
            this.startNode = startNode;
            this.endNode = endNode;
        }




        public Iterable expand(Path path, BranchState bs) {


            Iterable<Relationship> something = path.endNode().getRelationships(TripGraphRelTypes.VISITS,Direction.BOTH);

            return new  FilteringIterable<Relationship>( something
                    , new Predicate<Relationship>() {

                public boolean accept(Relationship t) {
                    //boolean result = tripRange.contains((Integer)t.getProperty(TripGraphProperties.VisitedByRel.departureToDsec.name()));


                        if ( (Integer)t.getProperty("departureToDsec") <= conditionFromTime ) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        if ((Integer)t.getProperty("arrivalToDsec") >= conditionToTime) {
                            return false;
                        }   

               if ( path.length() > 0 && (Integer) path.lastRelationship().getProperty("arrivalToDsec") < (Integer)t.getProperty("departureToDsec")){
                          return false;                        }        

                        return true;

                }
            });


        }









        @Override
        public PathExpander reverse() {
            //System.out.println("reverse");
            return this;
        }

    }


    PathFinder<Path> finderGood = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander, 10);
                        validPaths = filterValid2(finderGood.findAllPaths(n1, n2));

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.path.ShortestPath$DirectionDataPath.lastRelationship(ShortestPath.java:394)
    at au.com.company.tripresolver.CustomExpander$1.accept(CustomExpander.java:104)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.FilteringIterator.fetchNextOrNull(FilteringIterator.java:49)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.NestingIterator.fetchNextOrNull(NestingIterator.java:69)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.path.ShortestPath$DirectionData.fetchNextRelOrNull(ShortestPath.java:351)
        at org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.path.ShortestPath$DirectionData.fetchNextOrNull(ShortestPath.java:296)
        at org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.path.ShortestPath$DirectionData.fetchNextOrNull(ShortestPath.java:234)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.path.ShortestPath.internalPaths(ShortestPath.java:138)
        at org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.path.ShortestPath.findAllPaths(ShortestPath.java:110)
```

Comment: plz add the full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

The `Path` interfaces hasn't been implemented for shortestPath. See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/path/ShortestPath.java#L359 for the implemenation being used.

I don't know the reason why it's not implemented, but I guess such a reason exists.

As a workaround you use `BranchState` to store the last relationship. When the Iterable from your Pathexpander is consumed you need to store the current Relationship using `BranchState.setState(current)`. In `accept` you can use `getState()` to retrieve the previously stored state.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, would you be able to write up a small code snippet? I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say Iterable from the Pathexpander is consumed.

Comment: can you provide a sample graph.db as tar.gz for your use case?

Comment: PathFinder<Path> finderGood = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander, 10);

Comment: I guess you've misunderstood my request. I want to have the contents of your graph.db folder with some reasonable data in it to write a proper test case.